# Intel Jelly Bean images for emulator

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, intel, android-4.2-jelly-bean

How do I install the **Intel Jelly Bean image** for the SDK **emulator**? And if it isn't available, is there a possible release date?

Hey guys, I'm asking for ***JELLY BEAN*** images. ***Intel x86 Atom System Image*** for ***Android 4.1***. ;-)

Comment: You can download it from the Sdk Manager, should be under Api 16

Comment: Well, guys, I think I know how to install add-ons to the SDK. The reason it *should* be available is exactly why I'm asking. :-)

Comment: Are you saying you don't see it in the sdk manager? If thats the case, make sure you clear the cache. Tools-->Options-->Clear Cache

Comment: @mario, that's exactly what I'm saying. Do you actually have that in yours? Could you check, please?

Comment: EDIT: Nevermind i see your question now, I only have ARM EABI image

Comment: Ah, OK. Thanks for your help. Glad it's not a problem here then...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The JellyBean emulator is available now.[image]

Answer (score 2):

> How do I install the Intel Jelly Bean image for the SDK emulator?

There is no such image available at the present time.

> And if it isn't available, is there a possible release date?

None that has been announced.

Answer (score 2):

It seems Intel released a x86 Jelly Bean image at the end of August.

According to http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/android-41-jelly-bean-x86-emulator-system-image it should appear in the SDK manager (which is not the case for me), a manual installation method is also proposed.